# How do you properly return multiple values from a Promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I've recently run into a certain situation a couple of times, which I didn't know how to solve properly. Assume the following code:

```
somethingAsync()
  .then( afterSomething )
  .then( afterSomethingElse )
  
function afterSomething( amazingData ) {
  return processAsync( amazingData );
}
function afterSomethingElse( processedData ) {
}
```

Now a situation might arise where I would want to have access to `amazingData` in `afterSomethingElse`.

One obvious solution would be to return an array or a hash from `afterSomething`, because, well, you can only return one value from a function. But I'm wondering if there is a way to have `afterSomethingElse` accept 2 parameters and invoke it likewise, as that seems a lot easier to document and understand.

I'm only wondering about this possibility since there is `Q.spread`, which does something similar to what I want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript promise not passing all arguments (using Q)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17970420/1048572) and [How do I access previous promise results in a .then() chain?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can promises have multiple arguments to onFulfilled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773920/can-promises-have-multiple-arguments-to-onfulfilled)

Comment: De-structuring Assignment in ES6 would help. check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61136924/6270421)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

**You can't resolve a promise with multiple properties just like you can't return multiple values from a function**. A promise conceptually represents a value over time so while you can represent composite values you can't put multiple values in a promise.

A promise inherently resolves with a single value - this is part of how Q works, [how the Promises/A+ spec works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22776850/1348195) and how [the abstraction](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=54016) works.

The closest you can get is use `Q.spread` and return arrays or use ES6 destructuring if it's supported or you're willing to use a transpilation tool like BabelJS.

As for passing context down a promise chain please refer to [Bergi's excellent canonical on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250680/how-do-i-access-previous-promise-results-in-a-then-chain).

Comment: What's wrong with resolving with an object that has multiple properties?  Seems like a simple way to get multiple values out of a resolve.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to do that

Comment: You can also extend Promise to have `.spread()` like Bluebird showing in this related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22776850/1624862

Comment: The behavior of Promise.all() seems to contradict this.  `Promise.all([a, b, c]).then(function(x, y, z) {...})` works correctly in all modern Javascript engines with x, y, and z evaluating to the resolved values of a, b, and c.  So it's more accurate to say that the language doesn't let you do it easily (or sanely) from user code (because you can return a Promise directly from a then clause, you can wrap your values in promises and then wrap those with Promise.all() to get the desired behavior, albeit in a convoluted manner).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn That is just false, `Promise.all` fulfills [with an array](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-performpromiseall). In `Promise.all([a,b]).then((a, b) =>` `b` is `undefined`. That's why you need to do `.then(([a, b]) =>` which is a destructuring assignment

Comment: I would just concat them and split like the pros do

Answer (score 53):

you can only pass one value, but it can be an array with multiples values within, as example:

```
function step1(){
  let server = "myserver.com";
  let data = "so much data, very impresive";
  return Promise.resolve([server, data]);
}
```

on the other side, you can use the **destructuring** expression for ES2015 to get the individual values.

```
function step2([server, data]){
  console.log(server); // print "myserver.com"
  console.log(data);   // print "so much data, very impresive"
  return Promise.resolve("done");
}
```

to call both promise, chaining them:

```
step1()
.then(step2)
.then((msg)=>{
  console.log(msg); // print "done"
})
```

Comment: It's called *destructuring*, not "deconstructor", and it's not an operator :-/

Comment: Btw, you can use destructuring right in the parameters: `function step2([server, data]) { …` - that way you also avoid to assign to implicit globals. And you really should use `return` or `Promise.resolve`, not the `new Promise` constructor in your examples.

Comment: thans @Bergi for the recomendations!

Answer (score 22):

You can return an object containing both values — there's nothing wrong with that.

Another strategy is to *keep* the value, via closures, instead of passing it through:

```
somethingAsync().then(afterSomething);

function afterSomething(amazingData) {
  return processAsync(amazingData).then(function (processedData) {
    // both amazingData and processedData are in scope here
  });
}
```

Fully rather than partially inlined form (equivalent, arguably more consistent):

```
somethingAsync().then(function (amazingData) {
  return processAsync(amazingData).then(function (processedData) {
    // both amazingData and processedData are in scope here
  });
}
```

Comment: It is ok to return a `then` inside another `then` ? It is not an _anti-pattern_ ?

Comment: like @robe007 said, would't this be similar to 'callback hell'? here your nesting then blocks instead of callback functions, this would defeat the very purpose of having promises

Answer (score 7):

Simply make an object and extract arguments from that object.

```
let checkIfNumbersAddToTen = function (a, b) {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
 let c = parseInt(a)+parseInt(b);
 let promiseResolution = {
     c:c,
     d : c+c,
     x : 'RandomString'
 };
 if(c===10){
     resolve(promiseResolution);
 }else {
     reject('Not 10');
 }
});
};
```

Pull arguments from promiseResolution.

```
checkIfNumbersAddToTen(5,5).then(function (arguments) {
console.log('c:'+arguments.c);
console.log('d:'+arguments.d);
console.log('x:'+arguments.x);
},function (failure) {
console.log(failure);
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Whatever you return from a promise will be wrapped into a promise to be unwrapped at the next `.then()` stage.

It becomes interesting when you need to return one or more promise(s) alongside one or more synchronous value(s) such as;

```
Promise.resolve([Promise.resolve(1), Promise.resolve(2), 3, 4])
       .then(([p1,p2,n1,n2]) => /* p1 and p2 are still promises */);
```

In these cases it would be essential to use `Promise.all()` to get `p1` and `p2` promises unwrapped at the next `.then()` stage such as

```
Promise.resolve(Promise.all([Promise.resolve(1), Promise.resolve(2), 3, 4]))
       .then(([p1,p2,n1,n2]) => /* p1 is 1, p2 is 2, n1 is 3 and n2 is 4 */);
```

Answer (score 6):

Two things you can do, return an object

```
somethingAsync()
    .then( afterSomething )
    .then( afterSomethingElse );

function processAsync (amazingData) {
     //processSomething
     return {
         amazingData: amazingData, 
         processedData: processedData
     };
}

function afterSomething( amazingData ) {
    return processAsync( amazingData );
}

function afterSomethingElse( dataObj ) {
    let amazingData = dataObj.amazingData,
        processedData = dataObj.proccessedData;
}
```

Use the scope!

```
var amazingData;
somethingAsync()
  .then( afterSomething )
  .then( afterSomethingElse )

function afterSomething( returnedAmazingData ) {
  amazingData = returnedAmazingData;
  return processAsync( amazingData );
}
function afterSomethingElse( processedData ) {
  //use amazingData here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I reckon you should be doing.

### splitting the chain

Because both functions will be using *amazingData*, it makes sense to have them in a dedicated function.
I usually do that everytime I want to reuse some data, so it is always present as a function arg.

As your example is running some code, I will suppose it is all declared inside a function. I will call it *toto()*.
Then we will have another function which will run both *afterSomething()* and *afterSomethingElse()*.

```
function toto() {
    return somethingAsync()
        .then( tata );
}
```

You will also notice I added a *return* statement as it is usually the way to go with Promises - you always return a promise so we can keep chaining if required. Here, *somethingAsync()* will produce *amazingData* and it will be available everywhere inside the new function.

Now what this new function will look like typically depends on *is processAsync() also asynchronous*?

### processAsync not asynchronous

No reason to overcomplicate things if *processAsync()* is not asynchronous. Some old good sequential code would make it.

```
function tata( amazingData ) {
    var processed = afterSomething( amazingData );
    return afterSomethingElse( amazingData, processed );
}

function afterSomething( amazingData ) {
    return processAsync( amazingData );
}
function afterSomethingElse( amazingData, processedData ) {
}
```

Note that it does not matter if *afterSomethingElse()* is doing something async or not. If it does, a promise will be returned and the chain can continue. If it is not, then the result value will be returned. But because the function is called from a *then()*, the value will be wrapped into a promise anyway (at least in raw Javascript).

### processAsync asynchronous

If *processAsync()* is asynchronous, the code will look slightly different. Here we consider *afterSomething()* and *afterSomethingElse()* are not going to be reused anywhere else.

```
function tata( amazingData ) {
    return afterSomething()
        .then( afterSomethingElse );

    function afterSomething( /* no args */ ) {
        return processAsync( amazingData );
    }
    function afterSomethingElse( processedData ) {
        /* amazingData can be accessed here */
    }
}
```

Same as before for *afterSomethingElse()*. It can be asynchronous or not. A promise will be returned, or a value wrapped into a resolved promise.

---

Your coding style is quite close to what I use to do, that is why I answered even after 2 years.
I am not a big fan of having anonymous functions everywhere. I find it hard to read. Even if it is quite common in the community. 
It is as we replaced the *callback-hell* by a *promise-purgatory*.

I also like to keep the name of the functions in the *then* short. They will only be defined locally anyway.
And most of the time they will call another function defined elsewhere - so reusable - to do the job.
I even do that for functions with only 1 parameter, so I do not need to get the function in and out when I add/remove a parameter to the function signature.

### Eating example

Here is an example:

```
function goingThroughTheEatingProcess(plenty, of, args, to, match, real, life) {
    return iAmAsync()
        .then(chew)
        .then(swallow);

        function chew(result) {
            return carefullyChewThis(plenty, of, args, "water", "piece of tooth", result);
        }

        function swallow(wine) {
            return nowIsTimeToSwallow(match, real, life, wine);
        }
}

function iAmAsync() {
    return Promise.resolve("mooooore");
}

function carefullyChewThis(plenty, of, args, and, some, more) {
    return true;
}

function nowIsTimeToSwallow(match, real, life, bobool) {
}
```

Do not focus too much on the *Promise.resolve()*. It is just a quick way to create a resolved promise.
What I try to achieve by this is to have all the code I am running in a single location - just underneath the *thens*.
All the others functions with a more descriptive name are reusable.

The drawback with this technique is that it is defining a lot of functions.
But it is a necessary pain I am afraid in order to avoid having anonymous functions all over the place.
And what is the risk anyway: a stack overflow? (joke!)

---

Using arrays or objects as defined in other answers would work too. This one in a way is the [answer proposed by Kevin Reid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28703689/6276765).

You can also use *bind()* or *Promise.all()*.
Note that they will still require you to split your code.

### using bind

If you want to keep your functions reusable but do not really need to keep what is inside the *then* very short, you can use *bind()*.

```
function tata( amazingData ) {
    return afterSomething( amazingData )
        .then( afterSomethingElse.bind(null, amazingData) );
}

function afterSomething( amazingData ) {
    return processAsync( amazingData );
}
function afterSomethingElse( amazingData, processedData ) {
}
```

To keep it simple, *bind()* will prepend the list of args (except the first one) to the function when it is called.

### using Promise.all

In your post you mentionned the use of *spread()*. I never used the framework you are using, but here is how you should be able to use it.

Some believe *Promise.all()* is the solution to all problems, so it deserves to be mentioned I guess.

```
function tata( amazingData ) {
    return Promise.all( [ amazingData, afterSomething( amazingData ) ] )
        .then( afterSomethingElse );
}

function afterSomething( amazingData ) {
    return processAsync( amazingData );
}
function afterSomethingElse( args ) {
    var amazingData = args[0];
    var processedData = args[1];
}
```

You can pass data to *Promise.all()* - note the presence of the array - as long as promises, but make sure none of the promises fail otherwise it will stop processing.

And instead of defining new variables from the *args* argument, you should be able to use *spread()* instead of *then()* for all sort of awesome work.

Answer (score 0):

You can check **Observable** represented by [Rxjs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs), lets you return **more than one** value.

Answer (score 0):

Simply return a tuple:

```
    async add(dto: TDto): Promise<TDto> {
    console.log(`${this.storeName}.add(${dto})`);
    return firebase.firestore().collection(this.dtoName)
      .withConverter<TDto>(this.converter)
      .add(dto)
      .then(d => [d.update(this.id, d.id), d.id] as [any, string])
      .then(x => this.get(x[1]));
  }
```