# Multiple Promises - Where to resolve?

Tags: javascript, promise

**I Am New To PROMISE.**

I'm using nodejs promisify so I have the followings declared as promise for Redis

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const getAsync = promisify(client.get).bind(client);
const hmsetAsync = promisify(client.hmset).bind(client);
const hsetAsync = promisify(client.hset).bind(client);
const incrAsync = promisify(client.incr).bind(client);
const smembersAsync = promisify(client.smembers).bind(client);
const keysAsync = promisify(client.keys).bind(client);
const sismemberAsync = promisify(client.sismember).bind(client);
```

I have the following function and I do not know where is the right place to put the resolve(message)

```
function sendMessage(senderId = '', roomId = '', text = '', type='text') {

        var message = {}
        return new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {

    if (senderId == '') {
        reject('Invalid Characters in Sender Id or Sender Id is empty.');
    }


    if (roomId == '') {
        reject('Invalid Characters in Room Id or Room Id is empty.');
    }

    if (text == '') {
        console.log('Text:' ,text);
        reject('Invalid Characters in Text or Text is empty.');
    }
            //Check if Room Exist

            keysAsync('room-'+roomId).then((value) => {

                value == '' && reject('Room '+roomId+ ' does not exist.');
                sismemberAsync('roomuser-'+roomId, senderId).then((ismember)=> {
                    ismember == 0 && reject('User ' + senderId + ' is not a member of room ' + roomId);

                    const datetime = new Date();
                    incrAsync('messageId')
                    .then((id) => {
                        //Create the message Hash
                        hmsetAsync('messsage:'+id, 'id', id, 'roomId', roomId, 'senderId', senderId, "created", datetime, "text", text);
                        //add message to Set
                        saddAsync('roommessages-'+roomId, id);

                        message = { id: id, roomId: roomId, senderId: senderId, created: datetime, text: text }
                        resolve(message) //If i place here i don't get the resolve.

                    }).catch(err => reject(err))

                }).catch(err => reject(err))

            }).catch(err => reject(err))
        })
    }
```

And then I tried to call the function like this

```
tools.sendMessage(3, 4, 'Does this work?','text').then((result)=> {
  console.log('Send Message Result => ',result);
}).catch(err => { 
  console.log(err)
});
```

If I were to place the resolve(message) at where it is now, the above promise doesn't resolve, and "send Message result" doesn't show at all.

If i place it further out of the chain promise, the var message returns a empty object {}

**My question:** Where should I place the resolve in this kind of functions where I require multiple promise calls since I need to wait for multiple redis checks?

I have many functions that requires all my redis calls to be made before I can carry on to next action.

Comment: You have already promisified all asynchronous functions why exactly you need a new Promise constructor..?

Comment: i want sendMessage to be a promise so when i finally call sendMessage, it can be a promise chain? And you see my codes there are mutliple reject calls as well.

Comment: You shouldn't be wrapping anything in a new promise.  Just chain your existing promises together and return the promise from the chain.

Comment: Before the redis codes there's actually some codes to check if senderId, text, roomId contains illegal characters and reject() them.

Comment: @jfriend00 updated codes to show u what i meant.

Comment: Then, just return `Promise.reject(...)` for those check errors before your async operations.  You never need to wrap existing promises in another promise.  That is considered an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might consider refactoring your code as follows. If you need to catch errors at interim `.then()` stages then use onrejected callbacks.

```
function sendMessage(senderId = '', roomId = '', text = '', type='text') {
  return keysAsync('room-'+roomId)
         .then(value => value === '' ? Promise.reject('Room '+roomId+ ' does not exist.')
                                     : sismemberAsync('roomuser-'+roomId, senderId))
         .then(ismember => ismember === 0 ? Promise.reject('User ' + senderId + ' is not a member of room ' + roomId)
                                          : incrAsync('messageId'))
         .then(id => { var datetime =new Date();
                       hmsetAsync('messsage:'+id, 'id', id, 'roomId', roomId, 'senderId', senderId, "created", datetime, "text", text);
                       saddAsync('roommessages-'+roomId, id);
                       return { id: id, roomId: roomId, senderId: senderId, created: datetime, text: text };
                     })
         .then(message => doSomethingWith(message))
         .catch(errorHandler);
}
```

In the above code i moved the `new Date()` to one stage below where it is actually used however if for some reason you need `datetime` at the original `.then()` stage as shown in your question then you may as well do as follows;

```
function sendMessage(senderId = '', roomId = '', text = '', type='text') {
  return keysAsync('room-'+roomId)
         .then(value => value === '' ? Promise.reject('Room '+roomId+ ' does not exist.')
                                     : sismemberAsync('roomuser-'+roomId, senderId))
         .then(ismember => ismember === 0 ? Promise.reject('User ' + senderId + ' is not a member of room ' + roomId)
                                          : Promise.all([incrAsync('messageId'), new Date()]))
         .then(([id, datetime]) => { hmsetAsync('messsage:'+id, 'id', id, 'roomId', roomId, 'senderId', senderId, "created", datetime, "text", text);
                                     saddAsync('roommessages-'+roomId, id);
                                     return { id: id, roomId: roomId, senderId: senderId, created: datetime, text: text };
                                   })
         .then(message => doSomethingWith(message))
         .catch(errorHandler);
}
```

Comment: will sendMessage still be a promise then? I'm trying the codes now.

Comment: @Someone Special Yes. If nothing gets rejected then `sendMessage` will return a promise to resolve with the return value of `doSomethingWith(message)`. You may also consider moving the `new Date()` to one level down. It doesn't look like needed at where it is and passing it down to the next `.then` stage by array destructuring can be eliminated.

Comment: I have problem at hmsetAsync now where id is being passed as a promise but it needs to be a string.

Comment: @Someone Special Oops..! Moving `new Date()` below would also fix that error i suppose. I corrected the code.

Comment: You have an invalid semicolon and some missing `)` in that second code exmple.

Comment: @JLRishe Thank you for heads up. ESLint was not active. It should be fine now.

Comment: I don't really understand how it's chained, and I don't understand why is there suddenly a Promise.all, but it works! Are you able to tell me why is there a Promise.all there instead of just calling incrAsync like the first chain?

Comment: @Someone Special That also caught me on wrongfoot. In fact it's a very good point which might take more than a comment to explain so [I have just entered an answer to the appropriate question about that point.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49957460/4543207).

Comment: I tried to practice your solution on another function, this time Promise.Resolve doesn't seems to return the results. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49957878/promise-resolve-returns-undefined

Comment: appreciate if you can take alook at my codes and correct me.