# Promise.resolve returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, promise

This is a continuation of [Multiple Promises - Where to resolve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49956438/multiple-promises-where-to-resolve/49956666?noredirect=1#comment86931037_49956666) where I use the same code for different function.

**However, this time the Promise.resolve is returning undefined.**

**Results**
Thanks to multiple people pointing out the mistakes. There are multiple errors in the code which I realised I committed.

1) Using && in a non Boolean operation.

should use

```
(console.log(results) , Promise.resolve(results)
```

instead of

```
console.log(results) && Promise.resolve(results)
```

2) Using unneeded Promise.resolve - just return the results from the Async function will yield the same result as using Promise.resolve.

My final codes.

```
getMessages: function (roomId) {

    return keysAsync('room:'+roomId)
    .then(room => 
        room === '' ? Promise.reject('Invalid room Id')
                    : smembersAsync('room:messages:'+roomId))
        .then(messagesId => { return messagesId })
        .catch(err => { return err }))

}
```

**Original Question**
I'm using nodejs promisify so I have the followings declared as promise for Redis

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const getAsync = promisify(client.get).bind(client);
const hmsetAsync = promisify(client.hmset).bind(client);
const hsetAsync = promisify(client.hset).bind(client);
const incrAsync = promisify(client.incr).bind(client);
const smembersAsync = promisify(client.smembers).bind(client);
const keysAsync = promisify(client.keys).bind(client);
const sismemberAsync = promisify(client.sismember).bind(client);

getMessages: function (roomId) {

    return keysAsync('room:'+roomId)
    .then(room => 
        room === '' ? Promise.reject('Invalid room Id')
                    : smembersAsync('room:messages:'+roomId))
        .then(messagesId => console.log(messagesId) && Promise.resolve(messagesId))
        .catch(err => Promise.reject(err))

},
```

And then i call the function as follows

```
tools.getMessages('4').then((results) => {
    console.log('Messages in Room 4 => ', results);
  }).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

In my console, I can see the following results

> [ '191',   '192',   '193',   '194',   '195',   '196',   '197',
>   '198',   '199',   '200',   '201',   '202',   '207',   '208',   '209', 
>   '210',   '211',   '212',   '213',   '214',   '215',   '216',   '217', 
>   '218' ] //this is when i console log messagesId
>
> Messages in Room 4 => undefined //This is when i console log results

Comment: None of those calls to `Promise.resolve` or `Promise.reject` are necessary or useful.

Comment: And the `Promise.all()` appears to be unnecessary too.

Comment: The last `.then()` returns the value of `console.log()` which is undefined.

Comment: And yet, despite that, it's probably not the problem. We'll need to see (MCVE versions of) `keysAsync` and `smembersAsync`. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: @JJJ: Yeah. I assumed the undefined the OP mentioned was the one it logged, but...

Comment: There's 2 console.log, one in the getMessages, one in the call. Also i've updted the codes without Promise.All

Comment: `smembersAsync` seems to return a Promise, why not just return the function execution?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the response. I'm using nodejs and just promisify the redis functions.

Comment: Besides all `console.log(messagesId) && Promise.resolve(messagesId)` won't even run `Promise.resolve(messagesId)` since `console.log()` return value is `undefined` and will cut the short circuit done by `&&`.

Comment: @Redu console.log(messagesId) && Promise.resolve(messagesId) runs and returns all the numbers. But the Promise.resolve returns undefined.

Comment: @Luca Brilliant! I tried and that works, but is there a reason why my code now doesn't work?

Comment: Okay thanks i will try again!

Comment: Make it like `.then(messagesId => (console.log(messagesId), Promise.resolve(messagesId)))`.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial You really should not use `&&` if you are not doing a boolean operation. Use proper statements (`console.log(…); return …;`) or at least the comma operator (`(console.log(…), …)`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`console.log()` returns `undefined`, which is falsey. `&&` is a short-circuiting operator, and only evaluates the second expression when the first expression is truthy. So it's never executing `Promise.resolve(messagesId)`.

Instead of `&&`, use the comma operator. It evaluates both of its expressions and returns the second one.

```
    .then(messagesId => (console.log(messagesId), Promise.resolve(messagesId)))
```

Comment: Or stop trying to cram multiple statements into one and use braces with two statements (the more readable solution IMO).

Comment: And why even use `Promise.resolve()` at all.  That seems unnecessary.

Comment: I looked at that line and saw `||`. `||` wasn't there, but it's what I saw. Sigh.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the comma operator, -1 for not using it in your example code. You cannot use the comma operator in a concise arrow body - you are actually calling `then` with two arguments.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. I even answered a question a day or two ago about the dangers of comma operators, yet I fell into the trap.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm not going to address that. I haven't really examined the rest of the logic.

Comment: No logic to analyze. :-) Returning `Promise.resolve(messageId)` from a `then` handler is completely pointless; it's the same as simply returning `messageId` (but with extra unnecessary plumbing).

Comment: @jfriend00 you have pointed out Promise.resolve() is unnecessary but it wasn't useful to beginner like me because we don't understand. Now I understand that the redisAsync commands results are already a promise object, and so I can just return it.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial - See the answer I provided here for an explanation of why you don't need `Promise.resolve()` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

As has already been explained, you are getting the return value of `console.log(messagesId)` as your resolved value which is `undefined` because of the way the `&&` works and what `console.log()` returns.

But since, all you're really trying to do here is log the result and continue with the same resolved value, I'd suggest a cleaner way of doing that is to make yourself a little utility function:

```
function log(arg) {
    console.log(arg);
    return arg;
}
```

Then, you can change this:

```
.then(messagesId => console.log(messagesId) && Promise.resolve(messagesId))
```

to this:

```
.then(log)
```

Notice that within a `.then()` handler any plain value you return will become the resolved value of the promise chain.  You can also return a promise if you want to add another async operation into the promise chain, but if you already have a value, you can just `return value;`.  You don't need to `return Promise.resolve(value);`.  Inside a `.then()` handler, the `Promise.resolve()` is just extra, unnecessary code - just return the value directly.

Answer (score 0):

The Promise doesn't resolve with `messageId`, because `console.log()` returns `undefined`:

```js
console.log(Boolean(console.log("test")));
```

But this is not the only thing that you should change, in fact, you can leave out a lot, because the `smembersAsync()` function returns a promise, that you can simply return:

instead of

```
return keysAsync('room:'+roomId)
    .then(room => 
        room === '' ? Promise.reject('Invalid room Id')
                    : smembersAsync('room:messages:'+roomId))
        .then(messagesId => console.log(messagesId) && Promise.resolve(messagesId))
        .catch(err => Promise.reject(err))
```

simply use

```
return keysAsync('room:'+roomId)
    .then(room => {
        if (room === "") { Promise.reject('Invalid room Id') } 
        else return smembersAsync('room:messages:'+roomId)
    })
```

Comment: There's no unresolved promise here.  There's a resolved value that is `undefined`.

Comment: Where is an unresolved Promise in my code? I either return _a_ promise, or reject one on the given condiction

Comment: Your first sentence says "The Promise is never resolved".  That's incorrect.

Comment: So, what happens to that promise instead?

Comment: It's resolved with a resolved value of `undefined`.  That's a completely different thing than not getting resolved at all.

Comment: Ok, neat to know, I thought the resolver was never called in the first place