# how to display text value with argument from a resolved promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

as shown in the below posted code, i am returning a promise form a function.i would like to display a text message with argument when the promise is resolved. in other words, for the following line of code:

```
resolve("successfully saved the data to file:",{fileName+newExt})
```

when the promise is resolved i receive the aforementioned text but without the value of `fileName+newExt'

i tried the following:

```
resolve("successfully saved the data to file:",{d:fileName+newExt})
resolve("successfully saved the data to file:",fileName+newExt)
```

but the always the text gets displayed without the value of `fileName+ext`

**update**

as shown in code2 section posted below, i know how to print the message when the promise is resolved. but the text message in the `resolve()` gets displayed without the value of `fileName+ext`

**code**

```
export function writeToFile(fileName,contents,ext='.tiff') {
let newExt = ''
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
    if (typeof (fileName) !== "string") {
        reject(new Error("fileName is not a string.Did you pass string-object using new String(..)"))
    }

    if (contents == undefined) {
        reject(new Error("contents to be written to the file is undefined"))
    }

    if (typeof (ext) !== "string") {
        reject(new Error("extension is not a string.Did you pass string-object using new String(..)"))
    }

    if (ext.charAt(0) === '.') {
        newExt = ext
    } else {
        newExt = '.' + ext
    }

    if (!fs.existsSync(envVars.DEBUG_OUTPUT_PATH_FOR_TIFFS)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(path, {recursive:true})
    }
    
    fs.writeFile(envVars.DEBUG_OUTPUT_PATH_FOR_TIFFS + fileName + ext, contents,{flag:'w'},(error)=> {
        if (error) {
            reject(new Error("error occured while writing data to file.error:",error," file:",fileName+newExt))
            throw error
        }
        resolve("successfully saved the data to file:",{d:fileName+newExt})
    });
})
```

}

**code2**

```
response.on('close', async()=>{
const bufferedData = Buffer.concat(data)
writeToFile("test", bufferedData,'.tiff')
.then(statusMsg => {
    console.log("write-to-file status message:", statusMsg)
    fromFile(envVars.DEBUG_OUTPUT_PATH_FOR_TIFFS + "test" + envVars.CONST_TIFF_EXT)
    .then(geoTIFF=> {
        geoTIFF.getImage()
        .then(geoTIFFImage=> {
            console.log("geoTIFFImage:",geoTIFFImage.getBoundingBox())
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: add a `.then` and add your message after the promise resolves. if its printing before it means you are resolving it early

Comment: @innocent pls have a look at the code2 section added to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot resolve multiple values from the promise, which is why you don't get file string, or object.

So, you should change the result returned from the function.

For example, always send an object with message/result/error property

```
resolve({message:'msg'});
```

the same goes for error:

```
reject({message:error});
```

or maybe an array, or string, but only a single argument.

see:

[How do you properly return multiple values from a Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703625/how-do-you-properly-return-multiple-values-from-a-promise),

[Can promises have multiple arguments to onFulfilled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773920/can-promises-have-multiple-arguments-to-onfulfilled)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [JavaScript template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
resolve(`successfully saved the data to file:${fileName}${newExt}`)
```

If for some reason you do not have access to template literals, use the `+` sign to concatenate:

```js
resolve("successfully saved the data to file:" + fileName + newExt)
```

You can then call your function as follows:

```js
writeToFile(fileName, contents, '.tiff').then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

You also do not need to `reject` and to throw. Either one will reject the promise, and you can catch the error as shown on the example above with `.catch((error) => console.error(error))`

Comment: @innocent pls have a look at the code2 section added to the question