# Why does the jQuery success callback sometimes have 3 parameters and sometimes have only 1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

It appears there are two ways to construct a success callback for jQuery, one form having 3 parameters and the other having only 1. Which of these is correct, and why do both forms appear?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `success` function in the docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

`Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter or the dataFilter callback function, if specified; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object.`

So the success function can take 3 parameters: the data returned, the status of the response, and the XHR object. Most of the time, you only need the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are wondering why these two kind of ajax-using are both working?

```
$.post(url, callback-when-success);
$.post(url, data-to-be-posted, callback-when-success, server-return-datatype);
```

Let's have a look on the implementation(source code) of `$.post()`

```
jQuery.post = function( url, data, callback, type ) {
    /** the trick is right here ! **/
    // shift arguments if data argument was omitted
    if ( jQuery.isFunction( data ) ) {
        type = type || callback;
        callback = data;
        data = undefined;
    }

    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: method,
        dataType: type,
        data: data,
        success: callback
    });
    };
});
```

In fact, the `$.post()` always expects four parameter, and if you omit the `data-to-be-posted`(should be in the 2nd-pos)parameter, and the `success-callback` is placed on the 2nd-position, then the `data` would be assigned as `undefined` and the `success-callback` would still be the `success-callback`.

Answer (score 0):

The [`then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) and [`done`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) methods don't care how many parameters your callback has. A jQuery Promise<sup>1</sup> *can* resolve with multiple arguments, and all these arguments will be passed to your callback. Which and how many of them you actually want/need to use is your business.

Some examples:

- the animation queue [`.promise`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) resolves with a single argument, the elements collection.
- the `$.ready.promise` resolves with the `jQuery` function
- the internally used `Animation` promises resolve with two arguments
- the [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) promise resolves with the `success, statusText, jqXHR` arguments
- a `$.when(promise1, promise2, promise3, …)` promise resolves with arbitrarily many arguments
- a `promise.then(function() { return … })` promise resolves with the single `…` value

<sub>1: Notice that almost all other promise libraries put promises for single values only, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17970420/1048572) for example.</sub>