# Controlling the value of this in a promise

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I am wrapping some of the functionality of `XMLHttpRequest`. I am attaching the resolution of a deferrred to the event fired `onload`. IIUC `XMLHttpRequest` sets the value of `this` in the callback invoked by `XMLHttpRequest` to contain the response details (response text, status code etc.).

But I am using `q` and the value of `this` is lost somewhere in the resolution of the deferred. How can I ensure the response details are propagated to the callback resgistered with the promise `then`?

```
XMLHttpRequestWrapper.prototype.get = function(url) {
    var deferred = q.defer();
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onload = function() {
        // this now contains the response info
        deferred.resolve.apply(this, arguments); // 'this' is lost in the internals of q :(
    };
    request.onerror = function() {
        deferred.reject.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send();

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript promise not passing all arguments (using Q)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17970420/1048572)

Comment: q.defer();What is q here?

Comment: You cannot control the value of `this` in the callbacks. It is specified to be `undefined`.

Comment: @AbhisekMalakar https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: @Bergi, so I need to supply `this` as an argument to the callback registered with `then`?

Comment: If the callback wants to use `this`, yes. But usually it wouldn't.Go for `deferred.resolve(this);` if you expect your callbacks to deal with the whole request object.

Comment: @Bergi Create an answer and I'll accept. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the value of `this` is lost somewhere in the resolution of the deferred.

[The spec](https://promisesaplus.com/) requires that promise callbacks are invoked without any `this` values. That's why `resolve` and `reject` don't even accept a parameter for it. If a callback wants to use some `this`, it needs to [take care of that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572) itself.

> How can I ensure the response details are propagated to the callback resgistered with the promise then?

You [cannot fulfill a promise with multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17970420/1048572) - your attempt to use `apply` is futile. If you expect your callbacks to need access to all details, you should resolve the promise with the complete `request` object instead of its `.result` only.