# AngularJS passing more than one value to promise's success callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, deferred

I have the following service method:

```
ResourcesService.prototype.list = function ()
{
      var deferred = q.defer();
      var settings = fetchSettings();
      restService.getAll(resourceName, settings)
      .then(function (response) {
          deferred.resolve(response.data, {
               count: response.headers('cr_count'),
               total: response.headers('cr_total'),
               last: response.headers('cr_last')
          });
      }, function (error) {
          deferred.reject(error.statusText);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
}
```

As you can see I am passing two values to `deferred.resolve`, which are `response.data` and a metadata object.

Up in the call stack I have:

```
//"scenes" is an object that inherits from ResourcesService
scenes
.withLanguage('en-us')
.sort('creation')
.size(2)
.list()
.then(function (firstPage, metadata) {
     //firstPage is the "response.data" from previous method
     //metadata is undefined, but should be an object with all the values from the headers
});
```

Why is `metadata` undefined? I debugged `ResourcesService` and the headers are being read just fine, but the object passed is as argument to `deferred.resolve` is not being delegated to my callback function.

Does `deferred.resolve` support only one argument to be passed to the callback? Do I have to put this metadata in the same object along with the response?

Comment: Avoid the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572).

Comment: See also [javascript promise not passing all arguments (using `Q`)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17970420/1048572) (`$q` works the same in that regard)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass more then one parameter into `then` callback, only the one is expected and considered. What you can do however is to resolve your promise with an object. For example:

```
ResourcesService.prototype.list = function () {

    var settings = fetchSettings();
    return restService.getAll(resourceName, settings).then(function (response) {
        return {
            data: response.data, 
            metadata: {
                count: response.headers('cr_count'),
                total: response.headers('cr_total'),
                last: response.headers('cr_last')
            }
        };    
    }, function (error) {
        throw new Error(error.statusText);
    });
}
```

Note, that I also fixed [deferred anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns) in your code, you don't need dummy deferred object, because you already have promise you can return.

Then you would use it like this:

```
scenes
.withLanguage('en-us')
.sort('creation')
.size(2)
.list()
.then(function (response) {
    var firstPage = response.data,
        metadata =  response.metadata;
});
```

Comment: This approach is much nicer than mine, but why are you throwing an exception when there is an error? I tried returning `error.statusText` but my error callback is never executed. Instead, my success callback is called. How can I call the error callback without using `q.reject`?

Comment: This is exactly why I'm throwing: because if you return - it means that you handled failure, so sort of recovered and then in subsequent callbacks you will not get into error handler - because you already handled error. So in this case if you want to propagate erro down the chain you either $q.reject or throw. You can even just `throw error.statusText;` if you prefer.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer!. I ended up doing it your way and I like it more than before, plus I no longer depend on `$q` service.

Answer (score 1):

While @dsfq is right about not resolving with more than one argument, if you're using `q`, you could also wrap your resolved values in an array and use `.spread()` instead of `.then()` to split them across arguments.

Created:

```
  .then(function (response) {
      // Resolve with a single array
      deferred.resolve([response.data, {
           count: response.headers('cr_count'),
           total: response.headers('cr_total'),
           last: response.headers('cr_last')
      }]);
  }
```

Consumed:

```
scenes
.withLanguage('en-us')
.sort('creation')
.size(2)
.list()
// .spread() instead of .then()
.spread(function (firstPage, metadata) {
  // Works as expected
});
```